# How to fix this problem in postgres psql command?

Tags: postgresql, psql

In the psql shell . It working fine to run sql . But when i use the psql -c . It's has problem.

```
postgres@03e0948a4fed:/home/data$ psql --c "select version();"
                                                             version
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.4 (Debian 11.4-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit
(1 row)
postgres@03e0948a4fed:/home/data$ psql
psql (11.4 (Debian 11.4-1.pgdg90+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# truncate table "TEST"."E0005";
TRUNCATE TABLE

postgres@03e0948a4fed:/home/data$ psql --c "truncate" "table" "TEST"."E0005";
psql: FATAL:  role "TEST.E0005" does not exist

postgres@03e0948a4fed:/home/data$ psql --c "truncate table TEST.E0005;" `ERROR: schema "TEST" does not exist.`
```

Comment: I want to know how to use  psql --c to run the sql  truncate table TEST.E0005;

Comment: What's meaning "psql: FATAL:  role "TEST.E0005" does not exist  ?"

Comment: The command you put at the end is close, with the full command in quotes, but it should be -c instead of --c

Comment: @Jeremy  Thank you !! I tied to use '-c' postgres@03e0948a4fed:/$ psql -c "truncate table TEST.E0005;"
ERROR:  schema "TEST" does not exist  .  What's the problem ?

Comment: The parameter should be `-c` not `--c`

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems:

1. The argument to `-c` bust be a single string
2. You cannot nest the same quotes without escaping them.

So you have two solutions:

```sh
psql -c 'TRUNCATE TABLE "TEST"."E0005"'
```

or

```
psql -c "TRUNCATE TABLE \"TEST\".\"E0005\""
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Laurenz Albe's answer, you could also pass the command through standard input without worrying about quotes.

```sh
psql <<eof
  TRUNCATE TABLE "TEST"."E0005"
eof
```